# login in azure with username and password from command line

Tags: php, azure

I am working on Azure CLI from command line. To login in, there is command

```
azure login -u <username>
```

I am executing this command from php and php is not able to identify that it is asking for password hence it stops execution. is there any way that we can login with username and password or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following command to download the account publishsettings:

```html
azure account download
```

and then, use the following command to import the publishsettings:

```html
azure account import <path to your .publishsettings file>
```

See more details at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-connect/#configure, in this way, you only need to provide the path of your publishsettings file, Hope this could help you.

Comment: Getting error:   'download' is not an azure command. See 'azure help' and same for Import

Comment: we can use this link to achieve the same scenario: http://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings, if download the publishsettings file, could you use the second command? If you use "azure account --help", could find "account download [option]" and "account import [option] <file>"?

Comment: If you're getting the error `'download' is not an azure command`, first switch to Azure Service Management mode by running `azure config mode asm`.

Answer (score -1):

To use Azure CLI on you system and use Azure PHP sdk.

Please refer the link

http://phpazure.codeplex.com/